# In quantum mechanics how can eigenfunction, eigenvalues, matrix methods give us values of real physical quantities?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, eigenvalue

Eigenfunction, eigenvalues, eigenstates & matrix methods used in quantum mechanics seems purely mathematical.How can they give us values of real physical quantities in quantum mechanics?

Comment: Are you asking how it can be that mathematics helps us describe reality? Welp... That's not a physical question, hence not right for this site. Perhaps try over at [philosophy]? Hence, I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: This phenomenon, by the way, is nothing special to quantum physics. You're just as much using mathematics when dealing with e.g. Newtonian mechanics. Calculus, the theory of differential equations, etc. are all used there.

Comment: @Danu this person is asking about matrix mechanics as opposed to wave mechanics.  He/she did ***NOT*** ask about the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in the physical sciences.....

Comment: @user122066 The question is *literally* of the exact form: "[mathematical notions] used in [physics topic] seem purely mathematical. How can they give us values of real physical quantities in [physics topic]?". In particular, there is nothing to indicate that the OP is asking about anything specific to QM.

Comment: I want to know how ,in particular, eigenvalue of a particular hermitian operator gives us real physical value of physical quantity corresponding to that operator?We do not encounter this kind of measuring method in other branches of physics, so what special thing of quantum mechanics is signified by this method? Also, how this method was developed or even thought about at first place?

Comment: @Danu see above.....no need to get upset. It's just a person trying to learn

Comment: Your question is still not clear to me: Do you want to understand why the eigenvalues of Hermitian operators are real, or why Hermitian operators should be used to represent physical observables?

Comment: @user122066 I'm in no way upset---I'm just trying to keep up the average quality of questions on the site. In this case, I'm happy that the OP bothered to reply so that we can help him/her improve the question.

Comment: @user106360 your question is very clear to me but you may wish to elaborate this in your original question as it appears others are confused.  I might end up answering it myself since i uderstand what youre asking

Comment: All derivatives in physics are linear operators and so are all integrals, so it's not that linear operators don't exist outside of quantum mechanics, we just don't make a big fuss about their use.

Comment: If you interpret the probabilistic concept of "expected value" as measurement, e.g. the expected value of rolling a die is 3.5 or the expected velocity at any point is..., then you take $n$ measurements of, say, the velocity $f$, this simple calculation http://i.stack.imgur.com/digjZ.png hints at where all the formalism of QM comes from, it's just mathematical tools to calculate expected value

Comment: @bolbteppa the image at the link you provided combined with your comment is interesting & I think it answered my question (though I need to study it more to be 100% satisfied).Thanks for everyone's response (except one named Danu).

Comment: @user106360 I got that pic from page 1 of https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Stochastic-Calculus-Monographs-Mathematics/dp/3764326972/ & you should mix it with the discussion of Heisenberg in section 1 of https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Mechanics-Third-Non-Relativistic-Theory/dp/0750635398/ for a great way to think

Comment: Newton's equations of motion are purely mathematical, too. And so is Einstein's theory of relativity. But they predict how planets and stars move.

Comment: @user106360 asked: "We do not encounter this kind of measuring method in other branches of physics, so what special thing of quantum mechanics is signified by this method?" - The special thing about quantum mechanics signified by its need to use Hilbert spaces and noncommuting operators is that it is quantum, and not classical, physics. But instead of this correct answer, maybe you would prefer a wrong answer, e.g. that Jesus Christ is more important than his father? If it makes you happy, be my guest. It signifies the importance of Jesus Christ.

Comment: More seriously, eigenvalues are connected with real observables because a postulate of QM postulates that the measurement of an observable $L$ can only produce results that are eigenvalues of the operator $L$. Eigenstates are connected with real physics because the eigenstate is the right value of the wave function to be used after a measurement, before we make predictions of additional measurements. Matrices are real physics because every observable (what can be measured) is defined, by a postulate (law of physics), to be a Hermitian matrix with respect to a basis.

Comment: BTW in February, you were asking about spin-orbital interactions of nuclei - http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/239574/how-do-jj-and-ls-coupling-arise-depending-on-the-relative-strength-of-the-terms - and now you ask how Nature dares to use operators at all. Did you have a car accident in between? How did it happen that you didn't ask about the operators *before* you started to study Hamiltonians for spin-orbital interactions of nuclei?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go to QM to see that matrices are useful in representing physics; for example rotations - a very simple and physical motion - is represented by a matrix.

To see where the linear algebra in QM comes from, it might be useful to look at how it developed historically; for example, it was Einstein (according to Weinberg) that introduced the observable $A^n_m$ for the energy $E_n - E_m$ emitted in a transition of an electron from one orbital to another and used by Heisenberg in his Matrix Mechanics.

Though I'm not sure of the history, it wouldn't surprise me that this is why the spectrum of matrix - its set of eigenvalues - is called the spectrum.

Comment: To simplify my above question, please give me a everyday-life physical analogy/example showing hermitian operator operating on eigenstate to give value of quantity corresponding to that operator multiplied by that eigenstate.

Comment: @user106360: Harmonic systems work that way. You can calculate the eigenmodes of a bridge using a matrix for the mechanical coupling between parts with different masses and stiffness. I am frequently using electronics design software that calculates eigenfrequencies and modes of linear and linearized circuits. In system and control theory linear problems are being treated like this all the time. There is nothing special about these things. The only difference is the interpretation. In quantum mechanics we interpret these modes as potential futures, in classical physics as actual present state.

Comment: @user106360: As CuriousOne points out linear algebra is useful in modelling harmonic sytems; and this is in fact how Heisenberg modelling his physical system - an electron undergoing simple harmonic motion, before quantising it.

Answer (score 0):

The whole formalism of QM is based on a mathematical space called the "Hilbert space"  which is an infinite dimensional complex vector space equipped with an inner product.

A state is represented by a ray (and vectors $\psi$ belong to this ray) in this space. And the inner product of these states produces a probability to find a particle with the eigenvalue of an operator.

I.e.

$ O|\psi> = o|\psi> $

the object O is a hermetian operator which acts on the members of this vector space.

Indeed schrodinger wave mechanics formalism produces the same results but in general heisenbergs matrix mechanics are not only more illuminating but also more general and easier to work with in most cases.

For example, it is much simpler to study how a wavefunction $|\psi>$ evolves in space and time...especially the time evolution of a state is very simply a rotation of the state vector in Hilbert space

There's much much much more to the whole hilbert space formalism than this but this is merely to give you a flavor of what the whole fuss about maxtrix mechanics is

Ill add more later as my daughter is bugging me to play. :p

Answer (score 0):

The entire point lies in the correspondence between the mathematical language as description of the universe and the events therein taking place. Physics aims to describe the quantitative behaviour of nature with the purpose of making predictions; in order to do so mankind has introduced a language to communicate and describe the above (mathematics). Such language is, of course, arbitrary and predictions must not depend on its choice.

Before going to quantum mechanics, let us deal with the easiest of the phenomena: point particle classical mechanics, namely Newton's laws. These relate external forces acting on a particle with its acceleration, which in turn is the second order derivative of the position (with respect to the time variable). The full description of a mechanical system is achieved solving a differential equation with initial conditions and this already sounds pretty complicated and mathematical to me, not to mention that in case of interacting particles we need at least tensor calculus on differentiable manifolds. So your question

> How can they give us values of real physical quantities in quantum mechanics?

could become "How can tensor analysis describe the point particle and give rise to physical quantities?" and likewise for every other fundamental area of classical physics as well as thermodynamics, electromagnetism and so on and so forth. The answer is always the same: the mathematical description is nothing but a cooking recipe to get out some numbers, which happen to agree with the experimental results; whenever this happens we assume to have a good language and a good description of nature.

Coming back to your original question:

> Eigenfunction, eigenvalues, eigenstates & matrix methods used in quantum mechanics seems purely mathematical.How can they give us values of real physical quantities in quantum mechanics?

they are not *more mathematical* than any other theory in physics. As we have found a recipe to describe the Newton's law, we have likewise found a recipe to describe quantum mechanics given in terms of operator algebras on Hilbert spaces and we accept it because it agrees with the experimental results at the end of the day. Had it not agreed, we would have chosen a different one (and by the way there is plenty of alternative descriptions of quantum mechanics).